# SSSD+Samba+SSH GSSAPI authentication issues

Tags: ssh, centos7, kerberos, sssd

I am configuring SSSD+Samba+SSH on CentOS 7.6. So far I have managed to get all 3 at least working. SSSD is configured and joined using `realm join`. Samba is configured and connected to AD via `net ads join`. However, for some reason I cannot get GSSAPI authentication to work with this combination. SSH would constantly complain about keytab ticket issue. First, I noticed the kvno number became out of sync. SSH is attempting to use `kvno 2`, whereas the server has `kvno 4`. This causes GSSAPI authentication to fail and defaults to password login, which works.

**secure.log**

```
Apr 13 01:33:17 test-server sshd[10827]: debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\nRequest ticket server host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM kvno 2 not found in keytab; ticket is likely out of date\n
```

**klist -kt**

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4 04/13/2019 01:21:34 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   5 04/13/2019 01:27:02 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM
```

I determined that this was because I did not delete the computer object out of AD, though I don't know why SSH does not try to match the current kvno. I verified that AD is returning the correct number. After deleting the computer object, I repeated the steps to join. It re-created the computer object and reset the kvno to 2. However, now SSH complains that the keytab entry is encrypted using `aes256-cts` and cannot decrypt.

**secure.log**

```
Apr 13 02:01:35 test-server sshd[13788]: debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\nRequest ticket server host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM kvno 2 enctype aes256-cts found i   n keytab but cannot decrypt ticket\n
```

**klist -kt -e**

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   2 04/13/2019 02:00:54 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 restrictedkrbhost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 host/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 TEST-SERVER$@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/test-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   3 04/13/2019 02:01:10 RestrictedKrbHost/TEST-SERVER@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
```

So what exactly am I doing wrong here? Is SSH supposed always use `kvno 2`? What encryption is the keytab entry supposed to be for SSH to be able to read it? And how do I configure the encryption?

Comment: Can you share your sshd_config and krb5.conf?

Comment: Isn't it ss**h**d?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the domain username and password authentication working, as long as the user enters the name and password. The GSSAPI auth is, as you discovered, a little tricker.

What does `kinit -k $( hostname -f )@EXAMPLE.COM` return?

For resetting machine password, I like to use msktutil (from EPEL):

```
kdestroy -A
kinit domainadmin
msktutil -f -s host
msktutil -u -s host
kinit -k "$( hostname -s | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' )\$@MSAD.EXAMPLE.COM"
```

Source: my blog post: https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2018/09/06/kerberos-notes-and-sssd-internal-credentials-cache-error/